# mysqli_fetch_assoc() not working, unable to enter loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been trying to display the data from a table onto a page. The table is called `events` and the database is `school`.

As far as I know, I'm doing everything right, I've stored the query in a string, run it using `mysqli_query()` and later put the `echo` statements in a `while` loop while placing `$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` inside the parenthesis. Yet when I run it not even a single entry is displayed on the page.

Here's my entire code:

```
<?php
require("includes/common.php");
$query = "SELECT name,place,date FROM school.events";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Calendar Page for Trinity High School
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Events Calendar</title>
        <?php
        require 'includes/external.php';
        ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <?php
            include 'includes/header.php';
            ?>
            <div class="container">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Event</th>
                            <th>Place</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['place']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PS: Using some trial and error I found out that the program simply doesn't enter the `while` loop. Perhaps there's something wrong with the condition?

Comment: I changed school.events to events. Made no difference.

Comment: check your error log files.Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You're sure you're connecting to the correct database? You're sure your query returns any results?

Comment: I typed the same query in phpMyAdmin and it returned all the rows that are in my table. So yeah I'm sure there's no problem with the query.

Comment: not query, it's about connection ? are you sure connection created successfully?

Comment: Just after `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` and run your script and check.